# SharePoint hosted app part is not loaded with error "Refused to display <App URL> in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'"

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am working on a SharePoint hosted app. It runs fine when loaded by clicking on the app icon in Site Contents page. But when I add it to a page with client web part, it is stuck on the 'Working on it' loading message. The message logged in console says "SharePoint hosted app part is not loaded with error **"Refused to display  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'"**

is the url of the app. It is usually on a different domain like "https://tenant-89b6750c1b31e3.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/...".

The app contains nothing. Just a very new app.

Also,
I tried to figure out whether it is a server issue or page issue. I created an auto-hosted app for that. And the same way I added a client web part and added to the same page. And it works. As I believe the auto-hosted apps also run from different domain ( somewhere in Azure ).

So, why won't the SharePoint hosted app run?

*The difference I could locate is that - 
 Auto hosted app runs from Azure website, while SharePoint hosted runs from some SharePoint hosted sub web under same tenant.*

Had anyone faced the same issue, and resolved? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to the app page you want to display in an app part:

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I was looking for a programmatic way. Do you believe it could anyhow be possible to achieve rather than a manual process?

Comment: I don't see why a programmatic method is necessary; you can create a new page for an app part (create a new web part, select to create a page), and that gets added automatically.